# Odoo 12. why is there an error in view with xpath?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

After migrate from odoo 10 to odoo 12 I have this error. In odoo this this code worked fine

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="creative_form">
  <field name="name">creative creative form</field>
  <field name="model">creative.creative</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <header>

      </header>
      <sheet>
        <notebook>
          <field name='test'/>
        </notebook>
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>


<record model="ir.ui.view" id="creative_form_for_manager">
  <field name="name">creative creative form for manager</field>
  <field name="model">creative.creative</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="creative.creative_form"/>
  <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('creative.group_creative_manager'))]"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//notebook" position="replace"></xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

The error looks like this :

```
Error : ValueError: Element '<xpath expr="//notebook">' cannot be located in parent view
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure the first part in the following line `creative` should exactly match the folder name of the module or what is called module technical name

```xml
<field name="inherit_id" ref="creative.creative_form"/>
```